# How to prove that these two functions do not intersect?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I have this function $\;g(x)-x\;$ on the domain $\;0<x<\frac{1}{3}\;$, where

$g(x)=\frac{\left(9 x^2+1\right) \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{36 x^2+\left(1-9 x^2\right)^2 \cosh (2 \pi  x)}{\left(9 x^2+1\right)^2}\right) \sqrt{81 x^4+54 x^2+\left(1-9 x^2\right)^2 \cosh (2 \pi  x)+1}}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi  \cosh (\pi  x)}+\frac{18 \sqrt{2} x^2 \left(9 \pi  x^3+4 \tanh (\pi  x)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi }.$

I need to prove that $\;g(x)\;$ does not intersect $\;x\;$ over the mentioned domain. Calculating the first derivative does not work since it makes the problem more complicated. The plot of the functions is attached.[image]
Any hint or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You dont need to calculate the derivative. Just check if the right hand limit is positive as $x$ tends to zero.

Comment: @Sam The limits are $\lim_{x\to 0} \, g(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{3}} \, g(x)=1.33$ , but how can these help?

Comment: @PeterForeman I added the plot of $g/x$

Comment: @Mariya Is it not clearer now that $g(x)/x\gt1$ and hence $g(x)\gt x$?

Comment: This long expression is tricky to even input correctly. I got a bit different-looking graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7kbvmf01dv

Comment: @PeterForeman Now, it is clear that $g/x>1$

Comment: @MattiP. If you plot it on the mentioned domain, the result is the same.

Comment: I would try to plot $h(x)-x$ where $h$ are simplified versions of $g$ with $h >g$. If you can prove the result for a simplified version $h$... you win! You can start with for $h$ only the first term of the sum defining  $g$ for example and even try to simplify further.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net You mean $g\ge h$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Will it be sufficient to prove that $g'(x)$ is always greater than $1$? Does this imply that $g(x)>x$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri For sure! You we’ll spotted my typo.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thanks. But those expressions are not always greater than $x$. So, it does not help.

Comment: @Mariya Have you tried some at least? For example the one without the second term in the sum?

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

Denote

$$g_1(x)=\frac{\left(9 x^2+1\right) \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{36 x^2+\left(1-9 x^2\right)^2 \cosh (2 \pi  x)}{\left(9 x^2+1\right)^2}\right) \sqrt{81 x^4+54 x^2+\left(1-9 x^2\right)^2 \cosh (2 \pi  x)+1}}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi  \cosh (\pi  x)}$$ and

$$g_2(x) = \frac{18 \sqrt{2} x^2 \left(9 \pi  x^3+4 \tanh (\pi  x)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi }$$

$g_1, g_2$ are positive maps and we have $g = g_1+g_2$.

$g_2(x)/x$ is increasing on $(0, 1/3)$ as a product of positive increasing maps. Moreover $g_2(0.06) / 0.06 >1.0$. Hence we have the partial result that $g(x) - x$ is positive on $(0.06, 1/3)$. Remains to prove the result on $(0, 0.06]$.

Comment: Thanks. But, I think you mean $0.168$ instead of $0.06$. Anyhow, in this way, we have to prove some other things as well.

Comment: No. I mean what I wrote, i.e. $0.06$.

Answer (score -1):

$$ g(0)=0, g'(0)=1 $$
$$t(x)= x, t(0)=0,t'(0)=1$$
so there is a tangential contact for the two curves with two coinciding intersections as seen in your graph. It is confirmed that at the double root there is common slope$=1$

Comment: But this argument only contains the point $x=0$. How can I show that they do not intersect over the whole domain?

Comment: What you say is true if also the slope of function $g'(x)=1$ everywhere like function $ t(x)=x$ (which does not happen). It has a different curvature by second order derivative. If they intersect on the whole domain the only possibility here is that they must be identical.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Then, how do we know that there is no $x$ in $(0,1/3)$ such that $g'(x)=1$? I need to prove that these functions do not intersect.

Comment: @Narasimham The curves can intersect without having equal slopes at the point of intersection. The intersect may not always be tangential. Calculating the second-order derivative of this function is a nightmare and it just seems you used the graphical aid to drive the point that the second-order derivative is $>0$.

Comment: Nope. I used data at $x=0$ given by OP: $\dfrac {g(x)}{x}=\dfrac {g'(x)}{1} =1 $